# Type for simple dynamic key-name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to generate types for a dynamic key (that will be of type number). I have two very similar types:

```
type UseCalculatePayments = () => {
  totalPayments: number;
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};
type UseCalculateCommissions = () => {
  totalCommissions: number;
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};
```

The only difference is the first key-name (`totalPayments` vs `totalCommissions`). So I wanted to create a type for them both:

```
type UseDynamicTransactions = (type: string) => {
  [key: string]: number; // I want this type key to dynamically be called `total${type}`, so it would accept, for example, totalPayments, totalCommissions or totalSales, all of type number
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};
```

But now the condition has a type error of `Property 'condition' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'number'` as it presumably expects all the keys to be a number.

So my question is: how can the dynamic `[key: string]: number` type be corrected? I tried to use a `Record` type too, but this failed.

To give you some better context, see:

The stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-h3ckn4?file=App.tsx

The code:

```
export const App = () => {
  // const { totalPayments, aggregate, condition } = useCalculatePayments();
  const { totalPayments, aggregate, condition } =
    useDynamicTransactions('Payments');
  const {
    totalCommissions,
    aggregate: aggregateCommissions,
    condition: commissionCondition,
    // } = useCalculateCommissions();
  } = useDynamicTransactions('Commissions');
  const {
    totalSales,
    aggregate: aggregateSales,
    condition: saleCondition,
  } = useDynamicTransactions('Sales');

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <h2>Payments</h2>
        <p>Aggregate: {aggregate}</p>
        <p>Total: {totalPayments}</p>
        <p>Condition: {condition.toString()}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Commissions</h2>
        <p>Aggregate: {aggregateCommissions}</p>
        <p>Total: {totalCommissions}</p>
        <p>Condition: {commissionCondition.toString()}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Sales</h2>
        <p>Aggregate: {aggregateSales}</p>
        <p>Total: {totalSales}</p>
        <p>Condition: {saleCondition.toString()}</p>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

type UseDynamicTransactions = (type: string) => {
  [key: string]: number; // I want this type key to dynamically be called `total${type}`, so it would accept, for example, totalPayments, totalCommissions or totalSales, all of type number
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};
const useDynamicTransactions: UseDynamicTransactions = (type) => {
  // does some calcs etc...
  return { [`total${type}`]: 6, aggregate: 40, condition: false };
};

type UseCalculatePayments = () => {
  totalPayments: number;
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};
type UseCalculateCommissions = () => {
  totalCommissions: number;
  aggregate: number;
  condition: boolean;
};

const useCalculatePayments = () => {
  return { totalPayments: 5, aggregate: 100, condition: false };
};
const useCalculateCommissions = () => {
  return { totalCommissions: 3, aggregate: 20, condition: false };
};
```

Also, is an interface or a type better here? Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpp8pm) meet your needs? If so, I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a use case for [typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of mapped types and template literal types to create an object with the key you want.

Then combine it with the additional properties you want.

```
type TotalKey<Str extends string> = {
  [Prop in keyof "total" as `total${Str}`]: number;
};

type UseCalculate<T extends string> = () => {
    aggregate: number;
    condition: boolean;
} & TotalKey<T>;

type UseCalculateCommissions = UseCalculate<"Commissions">;
type UseCalculatePayments = UseCalculate<"Payments">;

const foo: UseCalculateCommissions = () => ({
    aggregate: 5,
    condition: true,
    totalCommissions: 5,
})

const bar: UseCalculatePayments = () => ({
    aggregate: 5,
    condition: true,
    totalPayments: 5,
})
```

To use it for your `useDynamicTransaction` you just need to specify the return type using this generic type.

```
function useDynamicTransactions<T extends string>(name: T): UseCalculate<T> {
    return {
        aggregate: 5,
        condition: true,
        [`total${name}`]: 5,
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how to pass in the type?

Comment: Maybe try to actually explain what you mean. Pass in what type where?

Comment: Sorry, I meant inside the function signature, e.g. `useDynamicTransactions('Commissions')` or `useDynamicTransactions('Sales')` as per the demo